# Separate labeled data

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix

I have a matrix of the size `n x p`(`n` data points). Using MATLAB k-means algorithm gives me an `n x 1` array, where each element specifies the label of the data point at the same position in the data matrix.

What is the best way to separate the original data into multiple matrices according to the label specified in the other array?

**Example**

```
data_points =

   -0.0168    0.0689
   -0.0064   -0.0632
    0.0527    0.0509
   -0.0468    0.0152


labels =

   1
   2
   2
   1
```

Thus the first and the last data point should be in a new array and the second and third should be in a new array.

Comment: I'm finding this question hard to understand.  Can you give an example, perhaps for the matrix [1,2;1,3;2,2;2,3;2,4;3,4]?

Comment: @user1837296 I updated my question!

Comment: It depends on what you want to do, but you may be better off not separating the data at all. When you need the submatrix corresponding to label `k`, just use `data_points(labels==k,:)`

Comment: @LuisMendo you are right, your solution works and there is no situation where i explicitely need the array seperated.